# Right continuity of a $\ P(X \le x) + P(X \ge t)/2 4

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\ X $ be a r.v. and I want to know if the following function:

$$\ G(t) = P(X \le t) + \frac{P(X\ge t)}{2} $$

is continuous from the right. I was told I can set $\ X $ to be a r.v. over the probability space $\ (\Omega, \mathcal F , \mathbb P) $ where $\ \mathcal F = \{ \emptyset, \Omega \} $ then the CDF of $\ X $ will be $\ 0 $ or $\ 1 $ then $\ G(t) $ will not hold right continuity. Not really sure where is the discontinuity point? Will it be at $\ 0 $ ?

Comment: By itself, the function $P(X\le t)$ is right continuous, but $P(X\ge t)$ is discontinuous from the right at any point $t^*$ where $P(X=t^*)>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! would it be a true to be continuous from the right if instead of $\ P(X \ge t) $ I had $\ P(X > t) $ ?

Comment: Yes, since $P(X>t)=1-P(X\le t)$.